# passing list to IN clause in HQL or SQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, in-clause

I get `List<Strings>` by executing a query. This must be passed to another query of **IN** clause values. How to pass them in **HQL**?

We can convert `List` to `Array` and can pass it, that's not a problem.

Finally, I must pass the list in `List<String>` or `Array` or `String` form to the **IN** clause.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
from AUTOS a where a.model in (select m.model from MODELS m)
```

or

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("select s.id from Salary s where s.salary < 50000 AND s.salary > 49980");
Query query2 = session.createQuery("from Employee e where e.id in (:ids)").setParameterList("ids", query1.list());
query2.list();
```

Comment: This is a good answer, however does not work for an empty collection.

Comment: is it possible to do it with 1 query? like in sql with sub queries?

Comment: finally got something

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while and you have been trying to pass the value of a different query as a queryParameter, you can also pass set or collections to in clause in HQL with '*elements()*' - here's a simple example of such usage:
[Hibernate query: does a Set contains a certain Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116179/hibernate-query-does-a-set-contains-a-certain-object)

Comment: This will do the same thing.. thanks for reply even it was late.. helpful to others..