# HQL query filtering by @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, many-to-one

I have UserClass which has a relationship with Roles:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="USERS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("ROLE_ADMIN")
@DiscriminatorColumn (name="ROLENAME", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=20)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true) 
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
    @NotNull(message = "Il campo RUOLO è obbligatorio")
    private Role role;

    //others fields


    //getter & setter

}
```

In UserDAO, i have insert / edit / delete ... function and also the one which gives me all users list:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
}
```

Now my question: i would like to build another function which gives me all users who have one of the roles i pass to the function:

```
public List<User> getUsers(List<Role> roles)
```

How can i do this? do i have to pass a List of Ids, or it's good pass a List of Roles?

in both cases, how can i write the the WHERE condition?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652937/passing-list-to-in-clause-in-hql-or-sql

Comment: thanks, i pass a list of role id and i create query with IN keyword