# Java Hibernate query Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

error message : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Transactional
    public List<String> getPartsFromMainOrder(String orders) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        String sql = "SELECT distinct partno FROM VendorOrderedItems  WHERE orderno in (:OrderNo)"
                + " ORDER BY partno";
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
         query.setInteger("OrderNo", Integer.parseInt(orders));
        List<String> partsList = query.list();
        session.flush();
        session.clear();

        return partsList;
    }
```

First method query is working . unexpected token error occure when it reach on query.setParameter("Partno",partno);

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Transactional
    public List<SelectedOrderItems> getSelectedOrderItems(List<String> lqs, String orders) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<SelectedOrderItems> lso = new ArrayList<SelectedOrderItems>();
        MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();
        String[] ord = orders.split(",");
        for (String partno : lqs) {
            String str1 = "SELECT price , orderno, quantity FROM vendorordereditems WHERE partno =:partNo "
                    + " AND orderno in (" + orders + ") "

                    + " AND price > 0 " + "ORDER BY price,orderno desc Limit 1";
            Query query = session.createQuery(str1);

            query.setParameter("partNo", partno);
```

Comment: And which token might that be? What's the value of ``orders``? How are we supposed to help you like this?

Comment: what is the data type of orders? That might be the issue in this case.

Comment: @Mailkov nice trolling

Comment: orders datatype is String .

Comment: @Shoaib and what's the value? It's very easy to break the querty if ``orders`` has a messed up format, such as an extra comma at the end

Comment: i edit the question for best answer please check the code now .

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in + " AND orderno in (" + orders + ") "

Why don't you remove it once and try. If it works, replace it with

AND orderno in  (:orders )

you can refer 
[passing list to IN clause in HQL or SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652937/passing-list-to-in-clause-in-hql-or-sql)

Comment: am upload complete code in which error ocurre please review it once

Comment: Please try step by step... remove " AND orderno in (" + orders + ") ". This will ensure if this is causing the issue